# This command cannot be used on multiple sections when copying discontinuous range

Tags: excel

```
 Do While ColumnCount <= lastColumn
    If Not IsEmpty(mailSheet.Cells(2, ColumnCount)) Then
        lastRow = mailSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, ColumnCount).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng1 = mailSheet.Range(mailSheet.Cells(1, ColumnCount), mailSheet.Cells(lastRow, ColumnCount))



        If rng Is Nothing Then

            Set rng = rng1
        Else
            Set rng = Union(rng, rng1)
        End If


    End If
    ColumnCount = ColumnCount + 1
Loop

rng.Copy
Worksheets("Sheet1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Hello, I have a sheet with 45 columns, all of which have headers. Of these columns, ~5 have 2 or 3 values below the headers.

My code above creates a discontinuous range (variable "rng"). I want to figure out a way to create a "continuous range"

I thought that using the pastespecial command would work, as seen in other stackoverflow questions (link: [Copying a discontinuous range from one sheet to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16473735/copying-a-discontinuous-range-from-one-sheet-to-another)). however, in my case, the code does not run beyond the

rng.Copy

line, and returns an error: This command cannot be used on multiple sections

Ultimately, I would like to email RNG, which I have a module for already. However, it needs to be continuous, so either I figure out a way to reformat through the copy/pasteSpecial or I create a new range.

Any tips are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to use `Range.CurrentRegion`. If A1 is the first cell, then go to the Immediate Window and type

```
?Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address
```

and see if that gives you the range you want. If you have some stuff adjacent to the stuff you want, CurrentRegion will be too big.  In that case, find the column with the most rows, and use that to determine how many rows your contiguous range has.

```
Sub CopyRange()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim lMax As Long

    'I assume you're setting this yourself
    Const ColumnCount As Long = 3

    'Loop through the columns and find the longest one
    For i = 1 To ColumnCount
        If Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row > lMax Then
            lMax = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
        End If
    Next i

    'If starting cell is A1, resize and copy
    Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Resize(lMax, ColumnCount).Copy

    'paste somewhere
    Sheet1.Cells(10, 10).PasteSpecial xlValues

End Sub
```